# Elasticsearch term query with colons

Tags: elasticsearch, escaping, braces

I have a string field "title"(not analyzed) in elasticsearch. A document has title "Garfield 2: A Tail Of Two Kitties (2006)".

When I use the following json to query, no result returns.

```
{"query":{"term":{"title":"Garfield 2: A Tail Of Two Kitties (2006)"}}}
```

I tried to escape the colon character and the braces, like:

```
{"query":{"term":{"title":"Garfield 2\\: A Tail Of Two Kitties \\(2006\\)"}}}
```

Still not working.

Comment: Show us your mappings, my bet is that this field has `"index": "no"` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Term query wont tokenize or apply analyzers to the search text. Instead if looks for the exact match which wont work as the string fields are analyzed/tokenized by default.

To give this a better explanation -

Lets say there is a string value as - "I am in summer:camp"
When indexing this its broken into tokens as below -

```
"I am in summer:camp" => [ I , am , in , summer , camp ]
```

Hence even if you do a term search for "I am in summer:camp" , it wont still work as the token "I am in summer:camp" is not present in the index.
Something like [phrase query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/.../phrase-matching.html) might work better here.
Or you can leave "index" field as "not_analyzed" to make sure that string is not tokenized.